# How to empty a reducer array after taking an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I have to display a list of users and on click of a button I want to display a text inside the button. UserHeader is a component that I import from my list of records. What I realize is that the action gets affected on all the list element once I click the button and I think this is because the reducer's state array gets filled with the record and everytime I display UserHeader it displays the text inside the button. I want to display the text only on the list element I am already dealing with, not the entire list. Please help me how can I do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser, selectPost } from '../actions';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {

  render() {

      return <button onClick={this.props.selectPost} className="header"> {this.props.select} </button>


  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    select: state.select
   };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { selectPost })(UserHeader);


//Reducer.js

export const Reducer_posts = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'FETCH_POSTS':
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }

};

export const Reducer_users = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'FETCH_USER':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const Reducer_select = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'SELECT_POST':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Also post your reducer function here.

Comment: done. Please have a look

Comment: Please refer this - https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

Comment: please put full your `UserHeader` component in your question.